# Extension of a smooth function in a set to an open set

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-topology, smooth-functions

Suppose there exists a smooth function $f$ from $U \subset R^n \rightarrow R$ (smooth at every point in $U$).
Is it true that there exist a function $g : V \supset U \rightarrow R$ in an open set $V$ containing $U$ such that g is smooth $V$?

Definition of “smooth at a point”

For any set  $A \subset R^n$, and $a \in A$, we say that a function $ f : A \rightarrow R$ is smooth at a if there is a smooth function $g: U \rightarrow R$ defined in a neighbourhood of a such that $g=f$ on $U \cap S$.

Comment: No, take $n = 1$, $U = (0,\infty)$ and $f(x) = 1/x$. An extension of $f$ cannot be continuous.

Comment: @blamethelag Sorry I wrote the question a bit wrongly. It need not be the same function. I have edited the question correctly now.

Comment: you can check that your definition of being smooth at a point is a generalization of the real definition of being smooth around a point. That is a function that is (really) smooth on an open set is smooth (in our meaning) at any point and the smooth representant is the function itself. Then considere again my example.